# Null reference exception using DbSet.Find()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, exception, nullreferenceexception

See screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, I'm getting a null reference exception when I attempt to call *Db.Players.Find()*, despite the fact that the value I'm giving it to find quite clearly exists in the table that I'm asking it to search.

I'm still just a bit of a newcomer to this, so I don't really have the foggiest idea what I could be doing wrong.

All I want is to be able look through the Players table, and add the player with the specified ID to Pairs.Players, which is simply a list of players itself.

Comment: Please post your code as code not a screen shot.

Comment: Are you sure it's not DB null? How is DB get initialized?

Comment: You need to split this line in 3 to debug or read the exception details. Create an empty player variable. Assign the find result to it...if not null. Then last step is to add it. Run and catch exception or see if you get player from db or not.

Comment: Copy error text instead of screenshot, please.

Answer (score 0):

`Pair.Players` is probably null.